# How I can store login user data in local storage in angular 8

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angular8

I want to store login user data in local storage in angular 8. and get the data of that user. in this, I'm not using Firebase auth service.

here is my login code

```
login(empId: string, password: string){
  return this.af.database.ref('Users/' +empId).once('value').then(
    snap =>{
      var userPassword = (snap.val() && snap.val().password)
      if(password == userPassword){
       // this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
      else{
        console.log("Incorrect Password")
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just looking for storing the login user in localstorage then you should use localStorage.setItem(key,value). And for settings up the user login things in angular, you must use canActivate which decides if a route can be activated based on user login like this:
auth.guard.ts

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
```

login.component.ts

```
onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
```

authentication.service.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`/users/authenticate`, { username: username, password: password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
```

Look at the below url in more detail:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-registration-login-example?file=app%2F_services%2Fauthentication.service.ts

I hope this is what you are looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Feels like there is more to your question, but if you are just looking to store a value in your browsers local storage its pretty straight forward..

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```